# MongoDB: How to update multiple documents with a single command not filtering data and updating it?

Tags: mongodb

```
    {
    bookingId: "123456",
    isAvailable: false,
    user: "John",
    RoomNo:101
    },
    {
    bookingId: "7777777",
    isAvailable: false,
    user: "Mike",
     RoomNo:102
    },
    {
    bookingId: "7777777",
    isAvailable: false,
    user: "Mike",
     RoomNo:103
    }
```

This is my API call,

```
    export const handleRoomCancel = async (req, res) => {
const bookingId = req.body.bookingId;  
await Room.updateMany({ bookingId: bookingId }, 
[{
$set: { isAvailable: true },
},
{ $unset: ["user", "bookingId"] },
]);
};
```

At the time of Room booking I have set the following properies to the Room. isAvilable:false, user:"Mike",BookingId:"7777777", but At the of cancelling rooms using booking Id it is cancelling rooms of other booking id ass well.
It is updating all records instead of only booking Id:7777777

Comment: You need to specify the roomNo that you need to cancel too. Otherwise, as your 2 documents are sharing the same bookingId, they will always be cancelled altogether

Answer (score -1):

its all OK! check your code and note that if you are using `ObjectId` you should proper format.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @mat-twg, It is the same as I have done, but still, I am not able to trace what could be the issue. I am generating the schema for the hotel room using Mongoose and in that, I have not defined the Booking id property. whenever a user books any rooms I add the booking id property to that room collection. I am not using the objectId for the Booking id. I am generating the Booking Id using 
const bookingId = String(new Date().valueOf()).substring(3, 13);
so for some collections, there will be no booking ID

Comment: We found out that the problem is not in queries to the db, but somewhere else... first, try drop the collection and letting Mongus create it again, the goal now is to repeat the test on your database, as an option you can use a docker container or atlas with default settings, also debugger can helps.

Comment: I found the reason by reading a thread from Stack Overflow. The reason for not working is I did not mention the property at the Mongoose schema modal, hence it was filtering all the records. when I mentioned the property, It started working fine. Thanks to all

Comment: nice, good job 